# Flutter best practices - How to call a dynamic method of a stateful widget from its state?

Tags: flutter

I am wondering what are the best practices when you need to call a dynamic method that is inside a stateful widget from its state.

I mean, I have a generic stateful widget that receives a function in parameter. And when I call it from its state Lint tells me that I have to avoid calls on a dynamic target. So how am I supposed to do it ?

Here is how my class is currently implemented

```
class MyStatefulWidget<T> extends extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function buttonFunction;
  final T functionParameter;

  const MyStatefulWidget(
      {Key key,
      this.buttonFunction,
      this.functionParameter})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            onPressed: () {
              widget.buttonFunction(widget.functionParameter);
            },
          ),
          title: Text("Some text"),
        ),
      ),
      body:...
}
```

Thanks a lot for advising me.

Answer (score 2):

I think much better if you will pass just a callback inside widget and then call your function with parameter from outside

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  const MyStatefulWidget({Key key, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          onPressed: widget.onTap,
        ),
        title: Text("Some text"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and somewhere in parent class add:

```
  void _onTap() {
    // call your function with parameter
  }
```

---

or, as mentioned in comment @dees91

```
class MyStatefulWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<T> onTap;
  final T parameter;

  const MyStatefulWidget({Key key, @required this.onTap, this.parameter}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          onPressed: () => widget.onTap(widget.parameter),
        ),
        title: Text("Some text"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and somewhere in parent widget

```
MyStatefulWidget<String>(onTap: _onTap, parameter: 'lets say its string')
```

and tap handler

```
  void _onTap(String parameter) {
    // call your function with parameter
  }
```

Comment: I would suggest to create generic `typedef void TapCallback<T>(T data);` and use it instead VoidCallback if you want to pass back some data of type T

Comment: @dees91 agreed.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick answer Dude ! It is perfectly what I needed.

Comment: Many thanks for the tip dees91, in this case it was not mandatory to pass the T object thanks to the callback. For my understanding when you create a typedef, it is like creating a delegate in C# right ?

Comment: @daseed ValueChanged already defined callback, it's the same as `typedef void TapCallback<T>(T data);` just another name

Comment: typedef is not delegate, it's alias https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/docs/language/informal/generic-function-type-alias.md